# Does the SO "proper question" policy clearly articulate the condition when one answers their own question?

Tags: feature-request

Note the confusion on this question:

[How can I do a CSS3 shimmer animation to an HTML target object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39733287/105539)

At the time that I asked that question, I already had the answer figured out. I was doing the "share my knowledge" thing where you type in your question, click the checkbox to answer it at the same time of asking it, and then post it all at once.

Instead, I get badgered that I didn't ask the question properly, when I clearly thought I did. The user that badgered me in the comments was wanting me to ask a question with half-written CSS in it as if I didn't already know the answer to the question, when clearly I did.

I'd like the policy documentation to be changed so that it covers a condition of when someone posts an answer at the same exact second that they post the question, through the "share your knowledge" checkbox option.

Comment: Question quality does not change if you plan on self answering or are looking for someone else to answer.

Comment: You want the "policy documentation" (whatever that is) "to be changed" but you don't say how you want it changed. If what you want is some sort of protection from people voting on self-answered questions, that's not going to happen. We don't want people to downvote a self-answered question *merely because it is self-answered*. However, self-answered questions can suffer from all the flaws that other questions suffer from, and thus can be downvoted and closed like any other question.

Comment: Well, Louis, read the question that I posted on the shimmer effect. Look at the tags I applied and how I stated the question. Obviously I can't "makeup" fake CSS that I tried because I had already figured out the answer. So, it's not like I could show "what have I tried?" because I have already figured out the answer.

Comment: This has happened to me 3 times when I posted a question that I already had an answer to, and gives me the general feeling that people are automatically downvoting self-answered questions. It gives me the feeling to never post a self-answered question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Volomike Considering that people were explaining to you why your question isn't a good question, it's pretty clear that it's *not* just because you're answer it.  Self answering questions are *hard*, very hard.  It's much harder to ask a good question when you know the answer already.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't seem to be working in Firefox.

Comment: @BSMP just a side note that I found the problem and fixed it in the answer I provided. Firefox doesn't support `background-position-x` property, so I had to use `background-position` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take the crux of your question at its face value here.

> In a web page, is there a way to do a CSS3 shimmer animation using keyframes? I'm more concerned with current browsers, not ones older than the release of IE11.

If you read this question from anyone else, what would you think of it?  My immediate opinion is that it's fairly broad; there could be a decent number of ways to tackle this with keyframes, or maybe keyframes aren't the best approach to this (not necessarily saying that).

In either event, it's left open-ended here.  There's not much else that anyone could go off of; you don't even specify the cardinality of the shimmer, where it starts, or for how long it lasts as part of your question.  It's just...open-ended.

I'm putting the fact that you self-answered the question aside since self-answered questions don't preclude one from writing a good question.  I'm not disagreeing with your solution, mind; I just think that, if I had stumbled across this question on my own, I'd probably vote to close it for being too broad.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question to post more details on the shimmer effect.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty clear that many Stack Overflow users aren't familiar with the practice of answering your own question, particularly the capability of answering at the time you're asking. People do tend to downvote these more heavily, and berate self-answerers in comments. It's a little disappointing.

I decline flags every day where people complain that "this person is trying to farm reputation by answering their own question and should be banned" or the like. I've lost count of the number of times I've had to provide a link to [this article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) to get people to stop flagging these. It's clearly a feature that not many people know about, but I don't know how to make this more well-known.

That said, when you are self-answering, you do need to make sure that the question would be viable without your answer. It has to be a good, on-topic question, and it has to be phrased in such a way that someone else could possibly provide an answer to it. I don't know if the comment to "show what you tried" would apply here, but maybe there's a way to narrow down your question or provide a little more background to it.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words and the empathy that you've seen exactly the type of problem I'm encountering on self-answered questions! Just now, I have edited the question based on Makato's suggestion in order to be more specific and less broad.

Comment: Kind of an aside, but it would be nice to have a flag for "This will be a self-answered question". There's been quite a few times where OP takes a while to post the answer, and the question WAS phrased as too-broad/off-topic, I've accordingly voted to close, and then everything "gets fixed" after the self-answer shows up.

Comment: @MarcB - A question's viability should be completely independent of whether it will be self-answered. Judge it or edit it based on how it stands at present. There's really nothing we would do with such a flag, since we can't act on how things will be in the future, just how they are now. If something is closed because of the initial state of the question, it can be edited into shape and reopened.

Comment: @MarcB: "*There's been quite a few times where OP takes a while to post the answer*" Then the OP needs to learn to use the "Answer your own question" feature at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page. That allows you to post your question *and* answer all at once.

Comment: @NicolBolas: figures... never having actually asked a question, I've never been into that part of the site...

Comment: Add a flag reason "The user answered their own question", upon selecting which the flaggers are dropped through a trapdoor to their eventual doom.  I don't know the details of the doom, but it should be evident by the extended wailing of the victims that it's pretty slow and painful.